# iOS Hockey SDK not reporting crashes

Tags: ios, crash, crash-reports, hockeyapp

I have installed hockey sdk on my native iOS application via cocoapods.
I've installed the default sdk using:

```
pod 'HockeySDK'
```

In my appDelegete I added the following lines:

```
BITHockeyManager.shared().configure(withIdentifier: "myID")
BITHockeyManager.shared().start()
```

The app Identifier is correct with the one on the hockeyApp dashboard, I'm sure about it because the user is correctly traced.
The problem is that the sdk does not report crashes of the app.

I've installed the application and then disconnected the cable and reopend the app. When the app crashes and when then i reopen the application a prompt does not appear to me.

What could be the problem? Maybe I missing something on the the installation of the Hockey SDK?

Thanks all

Comment: Did you contact their support? How did you crash the app (code sample and where in the app is this invoked and how)? Do you have any other crash reporting SDK installed (there can only be one)? You need to provide way more detail.

Comment: Same here. Have you found any solution by yourself in the meanwhile?